# Correlations with alien abduction experiences

Tags: reference-request, psychology, religion

I cannot find statistics about how many supposed alien "UFO abductees" have sleep paralysis.

I can't find statistics about how many alien abductees were hypnotized before concluding that they were abducted by aliens (because of the "buried" memories).

I can't find statistics about what emotions alien abductees associate with being abducted(good? bad?). What types of religious beliefs do those people in the study have?spiritual, christian, hells?,enlightenment?

I can't find statistics about how many "alien abductees" don't have religious beliefs.

Comment: Welcome to CogSci.SE! Have you tried searching "alien abduction correlation with x" in Google Scholar? I just performed this search and found quite a few results. https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=2017&q=correlation+with+alien+abduction+experiences&btnG=

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the money to pay to read studies that i have found that would provide them. I tried to search from free statistsics but can't find any yet. example of pay to get: http://psycnet.apa.org/buy/2002-17277-005

Comment: Have you tried using sci-hub? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub

Comment: No. I tried to find UFO abductee statistics in the search but found nothing relevant. Is are there other aspects of the website that I could use to find UFO abductee statistics?

Comment: The workflow I'm proposing to you:
1. Find paper on Google Scholar
2. Get URL of paper
3. Insert URL of paper into Sci-Hub to avoid paying

Comment: I do not know how use the search in sci-hub to get the articles that I would pay for otherwise for free. I don't know what you are referring to by "insert URL of paper". Which URLS? when I click on the articles URLS in google scholar the websites on which the article is stored appears. I tried to use those urls in sci-hub's search  but nothing relavent appeared.

Comment: By "URL of paper" I mean the URL of the article on the website that is pay-walled. For some reason PsychNet is not currently working. Regardless, [the paper you linked to originally](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/2002-17277-005) does not require Sci-Hub to read. [If you search for it on Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Memory+distortion+in+people+reporting+abduction+by+aliens.&btnG=), you will see a link to the PDF on the right of the article listing.

Comment: There are 5 questions in this post. Please research yourself a bit and ask one question per post. In it's current format it will hardly receive any answers I'm afraid